# How to paste text from clipboard on mac while running selenium - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyperclip

I have a function that verifies the data copied to clipboard

```
def verify_copied_transcript_data(self):
    selector = '//input[@type="text" and @name="topic"]'
    topic_field = self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(selector)
    topic_field.clear()
    topic_field.send_keys('')
    topic_field.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'v')
    topic_field_value = topic_field.get_attribute('value')
    self.assertTrue(len(topic_field_value) > 0)
```

I have verified that manually CMD + v does paste the copied text on the topic_field. Any idea why selenium would not simulate `topic_field.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'v')`

The function to copy the text is:

```
def click_copy_transcript(self):
    selector = '//div[@id="closeChatModal"]//span[contains(text(), "Copy All")]'
    self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(selector).click()
```

This copies the text on clipboard

Comment: Why do you want to paste text via keys combination instead of simply `send_keys("text to input")`?

Comment: @Andersson As the function states, I need to verify the text copied on clipboard

Comment: OK. And where is the code for *copying* text?

Comment: @Andersson Added in description

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

`ActionChains(driver).key_down(u'\ue03d').key_down('v').perform()`

or even:

`ActionChains(driver).key_down(u'\ue03d').send_keys('v').perform()`

I've checked it on a PC using the Control key instead of Command (obviously!) and both work.

PS. Perhaps first you might need to simulate a click into the field you want to paste the buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much ! wish I could upvote this a 1000 times, spent too much time trying different stuff that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
topic_field.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'v')
```

The full code would be:

```
def verify_copied_transcript_data(self):
    selector = '//input[@type="text" and @name="topic"]'
    topic_field = self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(selector)
    topic_field.clear()
    topic_field.send_keys('')
    topic_field.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'v')
    topic_field_value = topic_field.get_attribute('value')
    self.assertTrue(len(topic_field_value) > 0)
```

Also you can try to use ActionChains:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ActionChains(driver) \
    .key_down(Keys.COMMAND) \
    .key_down('v') \
    .key_up('v') \
    .key_up(Keys.COMMAND) \
    .perform()
```

Comment: I have added one more suggestion, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the following code copies the text to the *clipboard*:

```
def click_copy_transcript(self):
    selector = '//div[@id="closeChatModal"]//span[contains(text(), "Copy All")]'
    self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(selector).click()
```

Now, to copy the text from the *clipboard* you can use the [**`paste()`**](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) method from [**`Pyperclip – A cross-platform clipboard module for Python`**](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) as follows:

```
import pyperclip

def click_copy_transcript(self):
    selector = '//div[@id="closeChatModal"]//span[contains(text(), "Copy All")]'
    self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(selector).click()
    topic_field.send_keys(pyperclip.paste())
```

**Note**: As per [**`adam-p/cb.py`**](https://gist.github.com/adam-p/4173174) it is mentioned as:

> Python function to copy text to clipboard (so far only supports Windows).

Comment: `pyperclip.paste()` in this case still just sends the text, it's not a true CTRL+V it seems.

Comment: this will not generate any paste events